How to convert hierarchical TCL string value containing dictionaries into an equivalent Python hierarchical value?
I have hierarchical TCL values represented as strings like this: a {x y v w} b {i j k m}.
The above value contains 3 dictionary objects, which can be queried using TCL expressions.
I need to convert a value like this to a corresponding Python hierarchical value. For the above string the Python value would be: {'a': {'x': 'y', 'v': 'w'}, 'b': {'i': 'j', 'k': 'm'}}.
The standard Python module tkinter can convert TCL values to Python values.
But can it convert the hierarchical value, like I provided above, to its Python equivalent?

The problem is that Tcl dictionaries aren't actually a type, they're just a specific way of formatting a string (as are all other Tcl objects).  There is absolutely no way to tell that your two nested objects are intended to be interpreted as 2-element dictionaries, rather than 4-element lists, or 7-character strings.  So you're not going to find any generic solution, it's just not possible.

You logically need a schema to do the conversion. The schema just says "this is a dictionary of strings to lists of strings" (ie, what I believe you've got), but you need to have one, even if just in your head; arbitrary dist/list combinations are otherwise indistinguishable from strings. This makes generic solutions nearly impossible but specific ones easy.
With that in mind:
proc valueToPython(number) {subtypes value} {
    # This ignores the subtypes
    return $value
}
proc valueToPython(string) {subtypes value} {
    # This ignores the subtypes; raw triple-quoted has fewer surprises
    string cat "r'''" $value "'''"
}
proc valueToPython(list) {subtypes value} {
    set st [lassign $subtypes t]
    return [string cat "\[" [join [lmap v $value {
        valueToPython($t) $st $v
    }] ", "] "\]"]
}
proc valueToPython(dict) {subtypes value} {
    set st2 [lassign $subtypes t1 st1 t2]
    return [string cat "\{" [join [lmap {k v} $value {
        string cat [valueToPython($t1) $st1 $k] ": " [valueToPython($t2) $st2 $v]
    }] ", "] "\}"]
}
proc valueToPython {schema value} {
    set st [lassign $schema t]
    return [valueToPython($t) $st $value]
}

set MY_SCHEMA {dict string - list string}
set val {a {x y v w} b {i j k m}}
puts [valueToPython $MY_SCHEMA $val]

A list of numbers would be the schema list number, and nested dictionaries are perhaps like this dict number - dict string - string.
Producing sets and tuples is left as an exercise.

It's also possible to do "schema compilation" so that you aren't pulling apart the schema at runtime. That's getting to be a bit more code than I want to write...

The following algo would be a band aid for now, until you figure out a more comprehensible way to solve your problem:

I'm assuming that you have two levels, there is a overall res dict and a temp dict, curr. If you have more levels, you need a dfs recursive function (that you need to write).


import re


def f(tcl):
    st = re.split(r'(?<={)|(?=})|\s+', tcl)
    curr, res = {}, {}
    flag = True
    for i, ch in enumerate(st):
        if flag:
            top_key = ch
            flag = False
            continue
        elif ch == '{':
            key = val = None
            curr = {}
            continue
        elif ch == '}':
            res[top_key] = curr
            flag = True
            continue
        if not key:
            key = ch
        else:
            val = ch
            curr[key] = val
            key = val = None

    return res


print(f("a {x y v w} b {i j k m}"))
print(f("a {k1 v1 k2 v2} b {k3 v3 k4 v4}"))
print(f("a {k1 v1 k2 v2} b {k3 v3 k4 v4}"))
print(f("a {k1 v1 k2 v2} b {k3 v3 k4 v4 k5 None}"))
print(f("a {k1 v1 k2 v2} b {k3 v3 k4 v4 k5 None None None}"))
print(f("None {k1 v1 k2 v2} None {k3 v3 k4 v4 k5 None None None}"))  # Note: fails for these test cases




Prints:

{'a': {'x': 'y', 'v': 'w'}, 'b': {'i': 'j', 'k': 'm'}}
{'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, 'b': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'}}
{'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, 'b': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4'}}
{'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, 'b': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'None'}}
{'a': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}, 'b': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'None', 'None': 'None'}}
{'None': {'k3': 'v3', 'k4': 'v4', 'k5': 'None', 'None': 'None'}}


Complexity
O(N) Time and O(N) Space
